# Get logged in user's email address and pass it in an email message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC application that allows customers to log in and submit any queries they are experiencing, they enter their name and describe their issue.This query is then sent to our support email address via our server email, in doing so I need to include the user's logged in email address as a string in the email. I've tried a few ways but I experience run time error as the email field returns null.

My controller:This is in my controller method for the email

```
  Email.Body = $"<p><b>Name:</b> {support.UserNameSurname}</p> <p><b>Email:</b> {support.Email=User.Identity.GetUserName()}</p> <p><b>Message:</b> {support.SupportMessage}</p>";
```

The View

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserNameSurname, "Full Name" , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserNameSurname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserNameSurname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupportMessage,"Describe Issue", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SupportMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportMessage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Request  Help" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #0a9dbd;-webkit-text-fill-color: white; border-color: #0a9dbd; height: 40px; float:right;" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "CustomerView")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is that `User.Identity.GetUserName()` returns null value?

Comment: Did you try using User.Identity.Name ?

Comment: Yes that is returning null

Comment: That will only work if the username is an email. I would suggest he keep a session variable, or even for that matter an extension to session that has a getemail method, if the email is empty, load it from the db or where the data is stored.

Comment: You can use a `Session` collection after login, e.g. `Session["UserName"]` or use `User.Identity.Name` property (especially if cookie auth used). If the user name is not an email address format, you need to query the DB for getting his/her email address before sending mail.

Comment: @mahlatse, yes username is the email in my application - in email address format

Answer (score 0):

If i had to put what i wrote as an answer, you can go

```
public static string GetUserEmail(this HttpSessionState session)
{
    if(Session["Email"] != null)
      {
          Session["email"] = ..Set Session email here
      }

    return session["Email"]
}
```

then you can either create a set session method or just use the Session["key"] to set the value, then you will have access to your email.